# GUI scrollbar error

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to create a scrolling list within a GUI using nested panels. However, whenever I try to move the scrollbar in the GUI, I receive this error:

> ??? Error using ==> PyroGUI>slider Too many input arguments.
>   ???
>   Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Here is my code:

```
screensize=get(0,'ScreenSize');

handles.fig=figure('Position',[100 100 screensize(3)-150 screensize(4)-150]);


handles.hpanel=uipanel(handles.fig,'Position',[0.005 0.01 0.99 0.99],'Title','Panel');
handles.hsp = uipanel('Parent',handles.hpanel,'Title','Subpanel','FontSize',12,...
              'Position',[.025 .05 .3 .935]);

handles.hpop = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
       'Position', [20 30 20 700],...
       'Min',1,'Max',700,'Value',700,...
       'callback', {@slider,handles.hsp});

handles.pos=get(handles.hpanel,'Position');   
function slider()
        slidervalue=get(handles.hpop,'Value');
        set(handles.hpanel,'Position',[handles.pos(1) handles.pos(2)-slidervalue+1 handles.pos(3) handles.pos(4)]);
    end
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a callback function for `uicontrol`, it always needs two input arguments like this (even if you don't need them)

```
function slider(hobj, evnt)
        slidervalue=get(handles.hpop,'Value');
        set(handles.hpanel,'Position',[handles.pos(1) handles.pos(2)-slidervalue+1 handles.pos(3) handles.pos(4)]);
    end
```

Edit: See here http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_guis/examples-programming-gui-components.html